# update attributes in dynamic form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, dynamic-forms

I have dynamic form with conditional attributes.

E.g. if radio button "condition1" is checked, when "price" field hides dynamically via jQuery, and "percentage" field appears.

Let's say I created record with "condition1" radio box and set "percentage" value. Then, I decided to update record, and disabled "condition1", so percentage field hides, and I set new value for "price".

The problem is, that if I disable "condition1", "percentage" parameter is still present, and what I need is either "price" or "percentage" parameter at a time. I can removeAttribute() with jQuery on click, but this is bad user experience, because in some fields I have multiline textareas and I don't want to force users to write all again if they accidentally clicked on radio button.

I tried playing with ActiveModel::Dirty with no luck

in edit action of object's controller

```
   if @object.condition_changed? && @object.condition_was == "condition1"
      @object.attribute(:percentage, nil)
    end
```

Comment: before hiding of those element just set disabled property true so there values will not be submitted to the server and if you show again the text remain there you just have to set disabled property to false than

Comment: Thank you very much NitinJ, this is very good point. I tried that, but i didn't achieve my goal. If i update record and select another option in radio button, the old value will still persist in the database if I save changes. I need to clear data in the database for particular fields, if they are not related to option selected in the form to prevent storing incorrect data in the database

Comment: you can run a after update callback like after_update: set_nil_to_unrequired_field now def set_nil_to_unrequired_field update_column('your field ', nil) if "other field is present" end

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. update_column('percentage', nil) if condition == "condition1". Can you add your answer to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run a after update callback like

```
after_update: set_nil_to_unrequired_field 

def set_nil_to_unrequired_field 
 update_column('your field ', nil) if "other field is present"
end
```